# API for Google Image-based search

Tags: google-image-search

Is there a way to programatically upload an image (say a picture from the camera, taken in a mobile app) to Google's image-based search and receive Google's "best guess" what is on the image?

Results should be in JSON or XML, and must work outside of a browser.